# I uninstalled a package but custom fields stayed?

Tags: fields, custom, delete, uninstall

I installed the [PhotoLoader](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJfp0UAD) by GearDesign into my personal dev org and don't like it so I uninstalled it.. I'm still seeing remnants in certain places. The User object still has the fields it used and I can't delete them. On Accounts, the account team related list has a column called "PhotoURL" that I cannot get rid of.

How can an uninstalled package leave fields like this? What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall a package, custom fields on standard objects are deleted if they are NOT referenced by another component such as apex classes or workflows, layouts. What is the error that you see when you try to delete one of them?

Comment: They don't have any option to edit/delete, but I'm not really worried as much about those because they aren't front-facing, just still present in the Setup.. the PhotoURL thing is the main reason I asked this. It's a column on the Account Team list, which to my knowledge is not editable. More irritating than anything.

Answer (score 0):

When you uninstall the package, it deletes all the components which are present in the package from the org. So you should check it again.

Now there is a scenario where when package provider deletes some fields or components from managed package and upgrade the subscriber with the new version of package, old fields and components still remain in subscriber org to give subscriber a chance to review and act accordingly.

> Subscribers who upgrade to the new package version will still have the
>   deleted components available in their org. They’re displayed in the
>   Unused Components section of the Package Details page. This ensures
>   subscribers have the opportunity to export data and modify custom
>   integrations involving those components, before explicitly deleting
>   them.

See this:
[What happens when you delete components from managed package.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_managed_component_deletion.htm)